# GROOVY I am getting random backslashes when creating JSON file in Folder

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am having trouble compiling the JSON file. This is my method **(the main method just has the name of the method I am writing this code in it so I did not include the main method in here.)**

```
static void buildJSONFiles() {
        String commandJson = "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/docfiles/command_config.json"
        def data = [
                commands:
                        JsonOutput.toJson([new Commands(name:"upload", path:"\${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}", includeCommandName: true),
                                           new Commands(name:"file_info", path:"\${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}", includeCommandName: true)])
        ]

        println(data)

        def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
        def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
        File file = new File(commandJson)
        file.write(json_beauty)
        println(json_str)

    }


    static class Commands {
        String name
        String path
        boolean includeCommandName
    }
```

my output in the console does come out right like this

`[commands:[{"includeCommandName":true,"path":"${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}","name":"upload"},{"includeCommandName":true,"path":"${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}","name":"file_info"}]]`

but sending it to the JSON file it comes out like this

`{"commands":"[{\"includeCommandName\":true,\"path\":\"${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}\",\"name\":\"upload\"},{\"includeCommandName\":true,\"path\":\"${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}\",\"name\":\"file_info\"}]"}`

I understand that JSON backslash is a special character so I expected it to be only around the **:"${BUILTIN_EXE(command)}** but it is showing up everywhere where I did not even have a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have "random backslashes", you have double-quoted JSON, since you're using `JsonOutput` twice. `json_str` is *a string with JSON in it*, and then you're wrapping that as a JSON value inside more JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just got rid of the `JsonOutput.toJson()` that had the data wrapped in it and just left the data inside the `commands: `